# jQuery animation from multiple sources - affecting multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to simulate pumps, growing and shrinking as expected.

The process is:
pump 1 dumps into pump 2
pump 2 dumps into pump 3
pump 3 dumps into pump 1

Currently I have on/off buttons working pretty much as expected.  Unfortunately, for the demo - I'd like to have multiple buttons on at the same time.

Therefore if pump 1 and pump 3 are on at the same time I would expect pump 2 to remain constant.  Unfortunately, the way I have the jQuery animations working right now isn't mimicking this in real time.

Here's a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3939/

Ideally, what I'd want is something that grows/shrinks X pixels per second and is bound to a particular div - or something similar.  I'm open to ideas.

**Example jQuery:**

```
const secs = 30000;
const maxH = '250';
const minH = '0';

$('#btn-on-one').click(function(){
    $('#air-pump-one').animate({height:maxH}, secs);
    $('#water-pump-one').animate({height:minH}, secs);
    $('#air-pump-two').animate({height:minH}, secs);
    $('#water-pump-two').animate({height:maxH}, secs);
});

$('#btn-off-one').click(function(){
    $('#air-pump-one').stop().animate();
    $('#water-pump-one').stop().animate();
    $('#air-pump-two').stop().animate();
    $('#water-pump-two').stop().animate();
});
```

Comment: Well, what you made looks really nice but I don't understand the problem. If you want 1 one the pumps to be affected by another you need to use a callback function or run two `animate` functions on two pumps accordingly with the right calculations.

Comment: I don't understand. If Pump 1 pumps into pump 2 and pump 2 pumps into pump 3 and pump 3 pumps into pump 1, if 1 and 2 are on 2 should not stay the same, because pump 2 is not on and will fill up because of pump 1 pumping into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you asked, but I rewrote it a little according to my understanding. You can see if this will work for you or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/d21oq86d/6/

If you change the capacity just make sure the .pump-animation-box height css has the correct height to reflect the new capacity.

CSS:

```
.pump-animation-parent {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.pump-animation-box {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  height: 150px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.pump_contents {
  background-color: #04ACFF;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="pump-animation" class="pump-animation-parent">
    <div id="pump-one-animation" class="pump-animation-box">
      <div class="pump_contents" data-id="1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="pump-two-animation" class="pump-animation-box">
      <div class="pump_contents" data-id="2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="pump-three-animation" class="pump-animation-box">
      <div class="pump_contents" data-id="3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="button-parent">
    <div>
      <button class="btn-default pump_button" data-id="1">Toggle Pump 1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn-default pump_button" data-id="2">Toggle Pump 2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn-default pump_button" data-id="3">Toggle Pump 3</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
var pumps = {
    'status': {
    1: false,
    2: false,
    3: false
  },
  'contents': {
    1: 50,
    2: 50,
    3: 50
  },
  'capacity': {
    1: 150,
    2: 150,
    3: 150
  }
};

$(function(){
    init();
});

function init() {
    setInterval(function(){
    pumpCycle();
    updatePumps();
  }, 200);
}

function pumpCycle() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var target = i == 3 ? 1 : i + 1;
    if(pumps.status[i]) {
        if(pumps.contents[target] < pumps.capacity[i] && pumps.contents[i] > 0) {
        pumps.contents[target]++;
        pumps.contents[i]--;
      }
    }
  }
}

function updatePumps() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $('.pump_contents[data-id='+i+']').css('height', pumps.contents[i]+'px');
  }
}

function printPumps() {
    console.log(pumps);
}

$('.pump_button').click(function(){
    var pump_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  pumps.status[pump_id] = !pumps.status[pump_id];
});
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I wanted.  Thank you!